# Inverse of k = x/cosh(x)

Tags: approximation

Question inspired from Matt's video, [The bubble that break maths](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31Om4VrSzb8&t=671s)
Bubble shape is a cosh function: $\quad y = a \cosh((x-b)/a) $

With symmetry, we can reduce formula to: $ (R/r) = \cosh(H/r) $
where r = bubble minimum radius, R = bubble maximum radius

To simplify further, let $x = H/r\,,\,k = H/R :$

$x\,/\,k = \cosh(x)\quad\quad→ k = x\,/\cosh(x) $

Bubble will burst when $k > max(x/\cosh(x)) = 0.66274\,34193\,...$
This limited domain of $x = [0\,, 1.1996\, 78640\,...]$

Solving x from k is trivial, if we use iterations, say, Newton's method.
But, if we only need 3 digits accuracy, can we have a direct formula ?

Here is my attempt, by fitting a quadratic, and back solve for x
Points at x = 0.0, 0.4, 1.2:

$k ≈ -0.46590\,x^2 + 1.1114\,x$
$x ≈ 1.1927 - \sqrt{1.4225 - 2.1464\,k}$

Using Matts video example: $x|_{k = {0.25\over0.534}} ≈ 0.5465$
Convert back to bubble minimum radius: $r = {H \over x} ≈ {0.25 \over 0.5465} ≈ 0.4575$ meter

Actual minimum radius is 0.4652 meter, error of 1.7%
We can fit more points, but solving for k will involve solving for cubic (or higher) roots.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Empirical model**

Based on observation a simple model could be
$$x=x_*-\sum_{n=1}^m a_n (k_*-k)^{\frac n 2}$$
where
$$x_*=1.1996786402577338339 \qquad \text{and}\qquad k_0=0.66274341934918158097$$

Using $m=4$, we have $R^2 > 0.9999999$ and, as shown below, the parameters are highly significant
$$\begin{array}{llll}
 \text{} & \text{  Estimate} & \text{Std Error} & \text{Confidence Interval}
   \\
 a_1 & +1.7259717 & 0.000259 & \{+1.725464,+1.726480\} \\
 a_2 & -0.7108628 & 0.001734 & \{-0.714265,-0.707461\} \\
 a_3 & +0.4140864 & 0.003610 & \{+0.407005,+0.421168\} \\
 a_4 & +0.0944479 & 0.002348 & \{+0.089842,+0.099054\} \\
\end{array}$$

Making the coefficients rational (just to look nicer)
$$a_1=\frac{844}{489} \qquad a_2=-\frac{445}{626} \qquad a_3=\frac{535}{1292} \qquad a_4=\frac{131}{1387}$$
Now, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & x_{\text{est}} & x_{\text{sol}}\\
 0.00 & 0.000803 &  0.000000 \\
 0.05 & 0.050126 &  0.050063 \\
 0.10 & 0.100237 &  0.100505 \\
 0.15 & 0.151403 &  0.151730 \\
 0.20 & 0.203958 &  0.204184 \\
 0.25 & 0.258338 &  0.258392 \\
 0.30 & 0.315123 &  0.315008 \\
 0.35 & 0.375113 &  0.374883 \\
 0.40 & 0.439457 &  0.439204 \\
 0.45 & 0.509914 &  0.509740 \\
 0.50 & 0.589397 &  0.589388 \\
 0.55 & 0.683413 &  0.683588 \\
 0.60 & 0.805069 &  0.805292 \\
 0.65 & 1.013290 &  1.013080
\end{array}
\right)$$

Required accuracy obtained.

Comment: A nice bonus is for k > k0, estimate for x = NaN :-)

Comment: The same trick to get inverse of sin(x)/x, x=0 to π, does not work as well (even though it had similar shape). Perhaps we get lucky with this one.

Comment: Asymptotic Expansion around (X,K) of (1.19968, 0.662743): R := revert(series(K - (X-x)/cosh(X-x),x)) = 1.73717*√(x) - 0.838491*x + 0.889798*x*√(x) - 0.690279*x^2 + ..., --> inverse of (x/cosh(x)) around (X,K) is (X - R(x=K-k)).

Answer (score 1):

The solution of
$$ x \,\text{sech}(x)=k$$ cannot be explicit and then either numerical methods or approximations.

In your problem, what is interesting is the fact that the range of $x$ is quite limited. Assuming $k \geq 0$, $x$ varies between $0$ and $x_*$ corresponding to the maximum value of the lhs.  $x_*$ is the solution of
$$x \tanh(x)=1 \implies e^{-2x}=\frac{x-1}{x+1}$$ and then $x_*$ is explicit in terms of the generalized Lambert function. So, the maximum value of $k$ is
$$k_{\text{max}}=\frac{\sqrt{x_*^2-1} }{x_*}\coth ^{-1}(x_*)$$

We can expand $ x \,\text{sech}(x)$ as an infite series
$$ x \,\text{sech}(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{E_{2 n}}{(2 n)!} x^{2n+1}$$ we can use series reversion to any order. This will give
$$x_{(p)}= \sum_{n=0}^p a_n \, k^{2n+1}+O\left(x^{2p+2}\right)$$
The first coefficients make the sequence
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{13}{24},\frac{541}{720},\frac{9509}{8064},\frac{7231801}{
   3628800},\frac{1695106117}{479001600},\frac{567547087381}{87178291200},\frac{3676
   0132319047}{2988969984000},\cdots\right\}$$

To judge the quality, using the limited truncated series given above, give $x$ a value; from it compute $k$ and from $k$ recompute $x$. Here are the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x_{\text{given}} &x_{\text{recomputed}}\\
 0.00 & 0.00000000 \\
 0.05 & 0.05000000 \\
 0.10 & 0.10000000 \\
 0.15 & 0.15000000 \\
 0.20 & 0.20000000 \\
 0.25 & 0.25000000 \\
 0.30 & 0.30000000 \\
 0.35 & 0.34999998 \\
 0.40 & 0.39999980 \\
 0.45 & 0.44999859 \\
 0.50 & 0.49999245 \\
 0.55 & 0.54996756 \\
 0.60 & 0.59988397 \\
 0.65 & 0.64964481 \\
 0.70 & 0.69904911 \\
 0.75 & 0.74773420 \\
 0.80 & 0.79512362 \\
 0.85 & 0.84040336 \\
 0.90 & 0.88254661 \\
 0.95 & 0.92039514 \\
 1.00 & 0.95278735 \\
 1.05 & 0.97870666 \\
 1.10 & 0.99741676 \\
 1.15 & 1.00855418 \\
 1.20 & 1.01216141
\end{array}
\right)$$

For sure, above $x=0.75$, the agreement is not fantastic but, again, we could add as many terms as we want. More coefficients on request.

For your example where $k=\frac{125}{267}$, this would give $x=0.537391$ while the solution given by Newton method is $x=0.537414$ (relative error of $0.0043$%). Thsi does not seem too bad.

**Edit**

As shown above, the approximation is not very good for large alues of $x$. What we can do is to perform a single iteration of Halley method which would give as a better estimate
$$x_1=x_0+\frac{4 (x_0-k \cosh (x_0)) (x_0 \sinh (x_0)-\cosh (x_0))}{k x_0 (\cosh (2 x_0)-3)-4 \sinh (x_0) (k
   \cosh (x_0)+x_0)+2 \left(x_0^2+2\right) \cosh (x_0)}$$ $x_0$ being given by the series.

For example, for $x_{\text{given}}=1$, this will give $x_1=0.999460$ which is much better.

**Update**

For large values of $x$, we can make a series expansion around $x=1$, inverse it and obtain
$$x=1+t+\frac{e^4+6 e^2-3 } {4(1+e^2)}t^2+\frac{3 e^8+32e^6+74e^4-32e^2+19}{24 \left(1+e^2\right)^2}t^3 +O(t^4)$$ where
$$t=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+e^2\right) \cosh (1) (k-\text{sech}(1))$$

Comment: Unfortunately, revert of x/cosh(x) series expansion coefficients blows up, more terms make it worse.  It blows up even faster if we do expansion around 1, x-1 = 6.47250 z - 119.767 z^2 + 4121.88 z^3 - 175868. z^4 +  ... , where z = k - 1/cosh(1)

Comment: @albertchan. I know that and this is why I suggest one single iteration of Halley method.

Comment: I was referring to your comment, "For sure, above x=0.75, the agreement is not fantastic but, again, we could add as many terms as we want. More coefficients on request.".  It had an impression that more terms is better.  Perhaps this should be edited out ?

Comment: @albertchan. Use the first for $k\leq 0.55$ and the second for $k>0.55$.

Answer (score 0):

If x not too big, $k = x\,/\,\cosh(x) ≈ \tanh(\sin(x))$

$x\,/\,\cosh(x)\; = x - {1\over2}x^3 + {5\over24}x^5 - {61\over720}x^7\;+\;...$

$\tanh(\sin(x)) = x - {1\over2}x^3 + {37\over120}x^5 - {29\over144}x^7\;+\;...$

This approximation is easily reverted.

For Matt's video example, $k = 0.25/0.534 ≈ 0.4682$
$x ≈ \sin^{-1}(\tanh^{-1}(k)) ≈ 0.5325$

True x ≈ 0.5374, estimated x has error of 0.9%

Comment: Have a look at my second answer

Comment: That's it ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

From iteration formula, $x = k \cosh(x)$, x may have this form:

$x = K \cosh(K)\qquad$  // for some K, a function of k

Matching reverted formula of $\;x/\cosh(x)$, we have:

$\large K = k + {1\over2}k^5 + {43\over40}k^9 + {1\over1890}k^{11} + {80887\over25200}k^{13} \;+\;...$

Nice !
No k^3 and k^7 terms. Also, k^11 term has tiny coefficient.
To simplify more, let's try Pade approximation.

$\large k\left({20-33\,k^4 \over 20-43\,k^4}\right) 
= k + {1\over2}k^5 + {43\over40}k^9 + {1849\over800}k^{13} \;+\;...$

Using above Pade approximation of K, for Matt's example:

$k\,=\,0.25\,/\,0.534 ≈ 0.468165$
$K ≈ k\left({20-33\,k^4 \over 20-43\,k^4}\right) ≈ 0.480705 $
$x\,=\,K\,\cosh(K)\,≈ 0.537323\qquad$ // error 0.017%

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for comments*

Your idea of writing $x=K \cosh[K]$ is very interesting. Using more terms, we  have
$$K= k + {1\over2}k^5 + {43\over40}k^9\Bigg[1+ \sum_{n=1}^p a_n\,k^{2n}+O\left(k^{2p+2}\right)\Bigg]$$  the first $a_n$ making the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{4}{8127},\frac{80887}{27090},\frac{1094}{446985},\frac{303072008131}{2
   9286457200},\frac{4165543}{406756350},\frac{12966607541077}{331913181600},\cdots\right\}$$

You do not need to use the fact that the coefficient of $k^{11}$ is small since the exact $[5,4]$ Padé approximant is effectively
$$P_{[5,4]}=k\,\frac{ 33 k^4-20}{43 k^4-20}$$

Where I see a problem is that, using $p=20$, for $k=0.6$, we have $x=0.804726$ which is less accurate than the previous empirical calculation. Using the $P_{[5,4]}$ Padé approximant,we should have $x=0.798749$, the exact solution being $x=0.805292$. So, still the same problem when $k$ tends to approch $k_*$.